# Instagram - Is it possible to get users' recent media without being logged in?

Tags: php, javascript, json, api, instagram

http://followgram.me/search/ is a search engine where you can search user's recent media from Instagram and it displays the photos to you without ever being logged in.

How is this possible? When I checked the API you seem to have to be logged in to get query results or else it's a bad request. I have read around but can't find anything. Am I missing something super obvious?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following explains it (taken directly from http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/ )

> For the most part, Instagram’s API only requires the use of a
>   client_id. A client_id simply associates your server, script, or
>   program with a specific application. However, some requests require
>   authentication - specifically requests made on behalf of a user.
>   Authenticated requests require an access_token. These tokens are
>   unique to a user and should be stored securely. Access tokens may
>   expire at any time in the future.
>
> Note that in many situations, you may not need to authenticate users
>   at all. For instance, you may request popular photos without
>   authenticating (i.e. you do not need to provide an access_token; just
>   use your client ID with your request). We only require authentication
>   in cases where your application is making requests on behalf of a user
>   (commenting, liking, browsing a user’s feed, etc.).